# Package com.unity3d.player does not exist

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I tried to make Android (google) project from Unity (to obfuscate some dlls and then make apk by hands).

My project uses facebook sdk.
The problem is to make project without this error in facebook source files: 
"*package com.unity3d.player does not exist*".

It happens on:

```
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
```

I can't figure out how to solve this issue. What do I do wrong? any facebook settings wrong? missing some libraries? what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved by moving unity-classes.jar of main module to separate module and giving references to it for needed project modules

Answer (score 1):

02-16-2016

I had the same error.

Solved by rightclicking on the **unity-classes.jar** inside Android studio under zour libs folder. Then click *add as library*